# working with lynx in python terminal +displaying spanish characters not working

Tags: python, macos, unicode, lynx

I am querying lynx browser with a URL and getting the output from the terminal, but the problem is the output is from a peruvian website and the spanish characters are not being displayed correctly on the terminal. I am passing the -assume_charset and -assume_unrec_charset flags along with my call to the url so it should replace the character set with the one I specify if the website does not specify one. And for both these parameters I have tried Latin 1, Latin 3 and Latin 4 and none of them seem to work. I would like to know how I can fix this problem. I am using python subprocess module and passing the lynx query as a parameter to subprocess.Popen(...) and then reading the output from STDOUT. My code is the following:

```
    import subprocess
def get_urlData(url):
    cmd = "lynx -dump -nolist -notitle -assume_charset =\"ISO-8859-1\" -assume_unrec_charset=\"ISO-8859-1\" "+url
    lynx = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    file_data = lynx.stdout.read()
    #file_data = file_data.decode('ISO-8859-1','replace')
    return file_data
```

When I store the returned file_data in an object and attempt to print it on the python terminal, the following is a part of the output I get which I am including to clarify the problem:

Per\xedodo: Periodo de Gobierno 2006- 2011. 
Legislatura: Primera\n   Legislatura Ordinaria 2010\n   N\xfamero: 04903/2010-CR Fecha Presentaci\u0137n: 07/13/2011\n
Proponente: Congreso\n
Grupo Parlamentario: Multipartidario\n
T\xedtulo: LEY QUE EXTINGUE LA DEUDA TRIBUTARIA PROVENIENTE DE LA\n   IMPORTACI\u0136N Y/O VENTA DE COMBUSTIBLE TURBO A1\n

clearly the character \u0137 needs to be some other spanish character but I dont know how to get that to display on my terminal. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

\u0136 and \u0137  are UTF characters , your charset in cmd is ISO-8859-1... you must have the same character enconding.